# PHP codeigniter : I want to make an output product detail but the output shows only one productID and other productID can not output

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make an output product detail but the output shows only one productID and other productID can not output!

Is there a mistake on my controller, model, and view ??

View

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $key=>$value) { ?>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
     <h5><?php echo $categories[$key]->categoriesName; ?></h5>
         <?php if(count($categories[$key]->subs)>0) { ?>
             <?php foreach ($categories[$key]->subs as $k=>$v)  { ?>
                   <ul>
                      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>member/detail/"><?php echo $v->productName; ?></a> </li>
                   </ul>
             <?php } ?>
             <?php } ?>
        </div>
  <?php } ?>
<div class="row" id="productMain">
    <?php if(count($details)>0){ ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="mainImage"><img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/'.$details->photo);?>"
         alt="" class="img-responsive">div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box">
            <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $details->productName;?></h1>
            <p class="price">
                <?php echo $details->price;?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function detail($product_id=''){
     $data=array('title'   =>'Pasar Online | Detail Produk',
           'username'      => $this->session->userdata('username'),
           'categories'    => $this->categories_model->get_categories(),
           'details'       => $this->categories_model->get_details($product_id=''),
           'isi'           =>'member/detail');
     $this->load->view('template_home/wrapper',$data);
 }
```

Model

```
public function get_details($product_id) 
{
    $this->db->where("productID",$product_id);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product");
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row;
}
```

print_r($details)

```
stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0001 [categoriesID] => 1 [productName] => AAA ) 1
```

Where is my mistake? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your model use 
For object output `$row = $query->result();`
For array output `$row = $query->result_array();`

So change the function to

public function get_details($product_id) { $this->db->where("productID",$product_id); $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product"); $row = $query->result(); return $row; }

Comment: still there is an error message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Compare database column_name and views of $details->column_name

Comment: try to see the view from my question

Comment: Use print_r($details) and check..there is minor error I guess.

Comment: I already insert print_r in my question, problem is only one product in categories that can be output but other products can not be